# How to reference global static Dictionary without class name?

Tags: c#, .net, static, global

I have a file named `SQL.cs`, which looks something like this (queries redacted for brevity):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class SQL
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> SQL = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Customers",       "SELECT * FROM customers"},
        {"OverdueInvoices", "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE overdue = true"},
    };
}
```

From `Main.cs`, I'm having to reference it like so:

```
new MySqlCommand(SQL.SQL["Customers"]);
```

How can I eliminate the first `SQL`? I.e. I'd like to use:

```
new MySqlCommand(SQL["Customers"]);
```

Comment: You might be better off using a Resource file, be it a `resx` file if you are using Winforms or a `ResourceDictionary` if you are using WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably better to use `const string` instead of a `Dictionary`. Then you can reference them easily and get compile time errors.

```
public static class SQL
{
    public const string Customers = @"SELECT * FROM Customers";
}

//Wherever you're going to use it
new MySqlCommand(SQL.Customers);
```

Comment: Is there a name for this pattern? I'm doing this exact thing in a project involving a custom USB protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you can't do this. You could if static indexer were possible, but they aren't.

In C# 6.0, this will be available via the static `using` statement.

This code compiles in Visual Studio 2014 CTP 2:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApplication2.SQL;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string command = Commands["Customers"];
        }
    }

    public static class SQL
    {
        public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> Commands = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Customers",       "SELECT * FROM customers"},
            {"OverdueInvoices", "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE overdue = true"},
        };
    }
}
```

[image: Static using statement]